# How to tether a Windows Phone 8 phone to a Samsung tablet via Bluetooth?

Tags: 8.0, bluetooth, internet-sharing

I have a phone running Windows Phone 8.0 and I've been trying for hours to tether it to my Samsung tablet, in order to use the internet from my phone without using a hotspot or WiFi. I just want to use the apps and data from my phone on a bigger screen.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Something along these lines: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-beamer/b5511af6-cbd0-4945-9bf6-30cf0582043f ?

Comment: If you're willing to update to Windows Phone 8.1, you can use the Project My Screen option?

Comment: Why would you not use internet sharing over Wi-Fi? It uses less battery and is much faster!

Answer (score 3):

Starting with **Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1**, internet sharing can be done over Bluetooth, as well as over WiFi. To enable it, simply use the "Share over" dropdown list in the internet sharing settings app.

For more information:
[Internet sharing over Bluetooth comes via GDR1 update for Windows Phone](http://www.wpcentral.com/internet-sharing-over-bluetooth-comes-gdr1-update-windows-phone)

Answer (score 1):

Internet sharing over **Bluetooth is not supported**.

**Only Wi-Fi is supported** for internet sharing.

[Windows Phone How-to - Share my connection](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/connectivity/share-my-connection)

Comment: Per [this answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/4026), internet sharing over Bluetooth *is* supported.

Comment: @Indrek per that answer it is not supported. Please check again. http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/what-are-the-settings-required-for-internet-sharing-between-smartphone-and-pc/4026?noredirect=1#comment5857_4026

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've changed my vote (had to edit your post to do that, hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- pair your devices
- enable BT sharing in your windows phone
- join the Bluetooth personal area network (PAN) from your Tablet

(from a windows PC, the last operation is done via the menu of the BT icon in the systray)

Answer (score 0):

Internet sharing over **Bluetooth is now supported**, if you have Windows Phone 8.1 Developers Preview. You just need to get the latest **Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1**