# What are the settings required for internet sharing between smartphone and pc

Tags: lumia

After connecting my Nokia Lumia 525 to my pc(Windows XP), I am not able to use the internet on my pc through my mobile device. I have turned on the internet sharing option by going in settings yet it is not working.

Comment: Have you connected the PC to the phone's temporary WiFi hotspot? Internet sharing does not work via USB.

Answer (score 2):

Internet sharing is possible via Wifi on Windows Phone 8/8.1.

Bluetooth can be used to initiate the connection from a PC running Windows 8.1 and a Windows Phone running 8.0 Update 3 (GDR3) or newer.

[Official documentation - Sharing your connection](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/connectivity/share-my-connection)

Comment: For Windows 8.1, you *can* also share via Bluetooth

Comment: @RowlandShaw thanks, I've updated the answer!

Comment: @NeilTurner You got the Bluetooth part wrong. The PC connect to the phone over Bluetooth then turns internet sharing on, gets the Wi-Fi password, disconnects from Bluetooth and finally connects over Wi-Fi. Simply, **Bluetooth is only used to setup the connection**. Wi-Fi is used to transmit the data.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder You're right, I've changed the wording.